Regionalvarianten: Die Äpfel sind alle/aus?

Hier können Daten aus einer Internet-Umfrage eingesehen werden, die von Dezember 2007 bis November 2008 durchgeführt wurde. Diese Frage bezieht sich speziell auf die Verwendung der prädikativen Adjektive leer, alle und aus im deutschen Sprachgebiet. Konkret geht es darum, welche dieser Adjektive in welcher Region bevorzugt werden, um bestimmte Situationen auszudrücken. Besonders interessieren mich die Daten für Hannover, da ich dort wohne und kaum deutsche Freunde habe, die bereit wären, meine ständigen Fragen zur Verwendung bestimmter Wörter und Ausdrücke zu beantworten.
Allerdings stammen die Daten vor etwa 16 Jahren und könnten heute anders aussehen. Während ich den ersten beiden Bildern in diesem Aspekt noch Glauben schenke, zeigt das dritte Bild, das ich dem Post beigefügt habe, eine viel weniger deutliche Dialektverteilung in Niedersachsen.
Beispielsatz: Die Äpfel sind ausverkauft = Die Äpfel sind alle oder Die Äpfel sind aus?
Hier kommt leer gar nicht vor, was logisch ist, da Äpfel zählbar sind. Ich konzentriere mich daher nur auf die ersten beiden Varianten. Ich vermute, dass sie beide immer noch fast überall in dieser Bedeutung verstanden werden, jedoch gibt es sicherlich regionale Präferenzen.
Daher meine Frage an euch: Welches Wort wird heutzutage, insbesondere in Ihren Regionen, in solchen Ausdrücken bevorzugt? Besonders würde ich mich über Rückmeldungen von Menschen aus Hannover freuen: Welche Variante verwendet ihr normalerweise?

Interessantes Thema, aber wie soll man wissen, ob auch etwas in diesem nicht sonderlich langen Zeitraum verändert hat, ohne eine mindest ebenso umfassende Umfrage durchzuführen? Und hier funktionieren Fragen am besten, die Antworten haben, die Umfragen ist die Site nicht gedacht.

@CarstenS Ich hätte die Umfrage gar nicht angegeben und einfach danach gefragt, welches Wort man präferiert. Hätte es etwas verändert?

@CarstenS Na gut, ich formuliere meine Hauptfrage etwas um, damit sie nicht als eine neue Umfrage aussieht.

Verwandte Frage: Wie kam »etwas ist alle« zur Bedeutung »etwas ist aufgebraucht«?

Ich kann nur für den Osten Österreichs antworten. Hier werden seit jeher unverändert diese Varianten verwendet, die im Atlas der Alltagssprache abgefragt wurden:

Es ist keine Milch mehr übrig. Die Milch ist aus.
Der Motor springt nicht an. Möglicherweise ist die Batterie leer.
Die Äpfel im Laden1 sind ausverkauft. Die Äpfel sind aus.

Im Dialekt ist in der genannten Region anstelle des Wortes »aus« auch die Dialekt-Form des Wortes »gar« gängig. (»Die Mühch is goa.« »Die Äpfl san goa.« In Oberösterreich: »Die Öpfi san goa.«)
1 Im dritten Beispiel würde man in Österreich übrigens auch den Laden durch ein anderes Wort ersetzen: »Die Äpfel im Geschäft sind ausverkauft.«
